# Source IP of VMware storage paths

Tags: vmware-vsphere, iscsi

I have an iSCSI array that is working fine with my VMware host.  I'd like to disable several paths because they don't have end-to-end jumbo frames.  For the life of me I can't tell what the source IP address is of these paths.  I only see "Runtime Name" and it's "Target" in the web client but can't figure out how to associate the "Runtime Name" with a source IP address.  How can I go about getting a list of source and destination pairs that was generated automatically when I input the target IPs?  Thanks!

Comment: What version of vSphere, and are you using software iSCSI adapters, or something else?